# Abort error when Creating a file / Directory in Library directory on iphone

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm working on a cordova based ios application and in my application, I am storing the application related configuration files under library directory. The very first time when the application is installed on iphone these files will get created and are used futher. I was able to create files under the library directory in IOS7. But in IOS 8 Beta5, Xcode6 beta5, and cordova 3.5 when I try to create the files/Subdirectories under Library Directory I get ABORT_ERR.

Kindly advice.

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

i don't know exactly how you creat your project, but please read the [Cordova CLI-Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) to first off all get sure you "installed" all required stuff the right way.

After that you build a new Project, you do it this way over your terminal ->

- `cd ~/desktop`
- `cordova create media media.example.com media`
- `cd media`
- `cordova platform add ios`
- `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.yourneededpluginhere` (don't use
  this command, if you do not have any plugins)
- `cordova build`

After you finished this you go into your media directory where you can find the xcodeproject. You can open this and edit it via XCode. While you're working on your app, you can test it on the Build-in emulator in XCode, therefor you press the Run button in the top left corner.

Hope that helped you, if not, let me know and i'll explained more detailed!

Comment: have created my project by following the Cordova CLI-Guide and also I am using File api to create directory in the library dir. I am able to create sub-directories in Documents Dir but not in Library Dir.

Comment: what library dir are you talking about? On the phone, on your computer?!

Comment: Library folder on the iphone not on computer